# Does Apple Watch support AVAudioSession?

Tags: iphone, apple-watch, avaudiosession, apple-watch-complication

I want to know if I can use `AVAudioSession` for recording audio in Apple Watch, also I want to know if there is differences in audio quality recorded by Apple Watch and iPhone?

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `AVAudioSession` on watchOS.

`WKInterfaceController` has method `presentAudioRecorderControllerWithOutputURL` on watchOS 2 that is used to record audio. [Apple's docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/watchos/documentation/WatchKit/Reference/WKInterfaceController_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/WKInterfaceController/presentAudioRecorderControllerWithOutputURL:preset:options:completion:) have more information.

There's an enum `WKAudioRecorderPreset` ([Apple's docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/watchos/documentation/WatchKit/Reference/WKInterfaceController_class/index.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/WKAudioRecorderPreset)) you can use to specify quality. watchOS 2 is geared towards voice recording but there is `HighQualityAudio` option which records at 44.1kHz/96kbps with AAC or 705.6 kbps with LPCM.